# Spam being sent from my domain

Tags: dns, email, spam, spam-prevention

I have a suspicion that somebody is sending spam from my domain. Today I received an email from postmaster(`AT`)halliburton.com to htuwxjw(`AT`)example.com which said:

> The following email was blocked because it contained an attached file
>   type that is prohibited by the Halliburton email gateway:
>
> Sender:  htuwxjw(`AT`)example.com
>      Subject: ATTN: Important  notification for a Visa / MasterCard holder!

htuwxjw(`AT`)example.com does not exist. I have a catch-all email which receives any email sent to @example.com.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this? I have this TXT record on example.com: (MX records are Google's)

```
v=spf1 a mx ?all
```

I'm worried that any emails I send will be blacklisted if this person keeps sending emails as if they're from my domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ideal way to do this is to send a hard fail on email that isn't coming from your server IP address or your specified MX record by doing this:

```
v=spf1 +a +mx -all
```

This however will not stop the email from being sent. Spam filters do various checks on an email that has been sent out, one of them will be a check on the SPF record of the domain it is supposed to have come from and compare this to the IP address/MX record this has come from. This is one way to prevent and help disavow people sending emails pretending to be you but it will not put a complete stop to it. In a way this will make sure that the your domain is safe. Normally however it is the IP address that it is sent from that gets blacklisted.

Just a quick addition. You would probably be better using

```
v=spf1 +a +mx ~all
```

- - is a hard fail and may cause delivery problems
- ~ is a soft fail which shouldn't cause delivery issues (in case of a false positive however this is very low risk)
- if you do get stuck you could always try a wizard to do this for you. Try [here](http://www.spfwizard.net/)
- Hard Fail is recommended as it will turn away all that do not match where as a soft fail will just flag the mail and let it through
- `+mx` and `+a` is the same as using just `a` and `mx`

I personally do use the hard fail but some people do experience issues with this.

Comment: I saw your comment, thanks for expanding it into an answer. If I could ask for a little more :) in what cases might the hard fail cause delivery problems?

Comment: I've updated my answer, i beleive its incase of false positives however this is rate is very low with the rejection from SPF records. I would use a hard fail. Also i updated the difference between +a and a, which is not much

Comment: also make sure you wait for the dns to propergate before you try it out